# How to remove any node in a singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{ 
    int x;
    struct node *next;       
};

struct node *addNode(struct node *head, int y)
{
       struct node *traverser;
       traverser = head;
       if(traverser!=NULL)
       {                 
             while(traverser->next!=NULL)
             traverser=traverser->next;

             traverser -> next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
             traverser -> next -> x = y;
             traverser -> next -> next = NULL;
       }
       else
       {
             head= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
             head -> x=y;
             head -> next = NULL;
       }    
       return head;
 }

 void display(struct node *head)
 {   
     struct node *traverser;
     traverser = head;

     while(traverser!=NULL)
     {
          printf("%d\n",traverser->x);
          traverser=traverser->next; 
     }
 }

 struct node *InitializeList(void)
 {
       return NULL;
 }

int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head = InitializeList();
    head = addNode(head,2);
    head = addNode(head,15);
    head = addNode(head,5);
    head = addNode(head,8);
    display(head);  

    free(head);
    getchar();
}
```

I need to remove a node in main like this

```
struct node *head;
head = InitializeList();
head = addNode(head,2);
head = addNode(head,15);
head = addNode(head,5);
head = addNode(head,8);
display(head);  
removenode(5);
display(head);  
removenode(8); 
display(head);  
free(head);
```

That's my code for main() when it comes to delete specific node in my program.

But how can I do it? The removenode() is just function name what algorithm should I use? Or what or how to remove it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove node from single linked list.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432818/remove-node-from-single-linked-list)

Comment: In regard to the proposed duplicate: does c# have the same problems with regard to updating the caller's copy of head when deleting the first node? Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857457/deleting-node-from-linked-list-in-c is a better duplicate, but the answers there are incomplete.

Comment: @dmckee, you have to move the head no matter what language you're using.  I considered the question language-agnostic, since he was asking for an algorithm.  The only real difference with C is you have to make sure to free the node before you lose your pointer.  Either way, the question has been asked and answered a bazillion times.  There are 4 candidate duplicates just by scanning the titles in the "Related" sidebar, dealing specifically with deleting nodes from singly-linked lists, and I'm sure I could find more if I clicked through.  I just picked the first one that had a decent answer.

Comment: @Karl: I'm only asking for the best duplicate, and while you must always update the head, c's use-pointers-for-pass-by-reference syntax is well known for giving fits to programmers used to languages with real pass-by-reference semantics. In my experience, this is the single biggest hurdle for students working this problem in c.

Answer (score 2):

### Not quite a answer, just some general advice

For the purposes of figuring this kind of thing out, it is generally sufficient to solve exactly three cases

- The node to be removed is the head
- The node to be removed is the tail
- the node to be removed is interior to the list

---

The the big sources of trouble you will encounter are

- making sure that the "next" field in any preceding nodes get properly reset
- insuring that the caller gets or retains a *valid* pointer to the *new* head.

Note that there is a recursive implementation (think `n.next = remove(n.next,val)`) that makes these two problems one and the same, and that you can convert it mostly to a loop to prevent stack overflows on very long lists.

---

A sub-problem that may crop up is that of finding the node to be removed in the list. Can you makae you life easier by separating there part about finding the target node from a `remove(node* head, node* target)`?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm prototype needs to be:

```
struct node * removenode(struct node *head, int y);
```

Since if you're removing the first item, the original "head" pointer will no longer be valid.

The algorithm is simply to step through the list, remembering the previous item (and the head), and looking for the data. When found, set previous item's next pointer to be the current item's next.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, to remove any node, what you need to do is:

1) Point to the item that is pointing to the node you want to delete.

2) Set the reference to the item you want to delete to the item you want to delete's next item.

3) Delete the item you want to delete.

That way, you chain is maintained and you've freed that element from memory.

Like so:

```
Head -> Item1 -> Item2 -> Item3 -> NULL
```

If you want to delete Item2, you go like this:

```
Head -> Item1 -> Item2 -> Item3 -> NULL
          ^       ^   (Grab pointers to these items)
```

Set Item1's next to Item2's next, then delete Item2.

```
           /--------------\
Head -> Item1    Item2 -> Item3 -> NULL
          ^       ^ (Delete 2)
```

EDIT: Deleting Item or Item3:

```
Head -> Item1 -> Item2 -> Item3 -> NULL
 ^       ^   (Grab pointers to these items)
```

Repoint head to Item2, then delete Item1:

```
   /--------------\
Head    Item1 -> Item2 -> Item3 -> NULL
 ^       ^ (Delete 1)
```

OR

```
Head -> Item1 -> Item2 -> Item3 -> NULL
                    ^       ^   (Grab pointers to these items)
```

Repoint head to Item2, then delete Item1:

```
                    /--------------\
Head -> Item1 -> Item2   Item3 -> NULL
                   ^       ^ (Delete 3)
```

Comment: The algortihm works for both deleting Item1 and Item3. However, I'll show the same set in my answer.

Comment: It's clear it works for the tail (almost all approaches get that one for free), but you generally need to show that you've solved the update problem for deleting the head. See [unwind's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433967/how-to-remove-any-node-in-a-singly-linked-list/5434036#5434036).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works out for you or not, perhaps was stored in my PC somewhere for a situation like this:

```
void RemoveNode(struct node*x)
{
    struct node *temp=x,*tempo=NULL;
    int i=0,n;
    printf("\nWould you like to delete a node?\nPress 1 for Yes 2 for No: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if(i==1)
    {
        printf("Enter nth node to be deleted");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        i=0;
        if(n==1)
        {
        x=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        }
        while(i<n-2)
        {
        temp=temp->next;
        i++;
        }
        if(temp->next->next==NULL)
        {
        tempo=temp->next;
        temp->next=NULL;
        free(tempo);
        }
        else
        {
        tempo=temp->next;
        temp->next=temp->next->next;
        free(tempo);
        }
    }
    else
    printf("\n No Changes Made\nExiting....");
}
```

It always the Head that counts.