# Using Pass by reference with linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference

So I've use pass by reference on my linked list code but the problem is it's not printing soo how do  I actually fix this?

**my code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
      int x;
      struct node *next;
};

void add(struct node **root, int x)
{
      struct node *conductor;
      if(root==NULL)
      {
          (*root)=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          (*root)->x=x;
          (*root)->next=NULL ;         
      }
      else
      {
          conductor = *root;
          while(conductor->next!=NULL)
          {
              conductor = conductor -> next;             
          }
          conductor->next=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          conductor->next->x=x;
          conductor->next->next=NULL;
      } 
}      

void display(struct node *root)
{
      struct node *conductor;
      conductor=root;
      while(conductor!=NULL)
      {
           printf("%d",conductor->x);
           conductor = conductor ->next;                           
      } 
}



int main()
{
    struct node *root;
    root=NULL;
    add(&root,5);
    add(&root,4);
    display(root);
    free(root);
    system("pause");
 }
```

In better form
http://codepad.org/CPdUvK0x

Isn't it all nodes in my program are linked?

Comment: Please accept an answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433967/how-to-remove-any-node-in-a-singly-linked-list by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: "pass by reference" does not exist in C. But there is pass by value for which the value is a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

```
void add(struct node **root, int x)
 {
      struct node *conductor;
      if(root==NULL)
```

That should be if `(*root == NULL)`

Since you're calling `add(&root...` `root` will never be NULL.

Comment: Thank you :) This is the answer so silly of me of not seeing that I was laughing my butt of when I saw this answer silly me xDD

Answer (score 2):

The check:

```
if(root==NULL)
```

should be

```
if(*root==NULL)
```

as `root` is being passed by address.

Also you do `free(root)` to free the entire list which is incorrect as it frees only the first node and makes the other nodes unreachable causing memory leak. To fix this you need to free the nodes one by one as:

```
struct node *tmp = root;
while(root) {
  tmp = root->next;
  free(root);
  root = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in `add()`:

```
if(root==NULL)
```

this test is wrong: root being passed *by reference* is never NULL (see in the main, it contains the address of the root node). you should correctly test if the rrot node is NULL:

```
if (*root == NULL)
```

i would also add that your way of freeing the memory allocated for the ist is wrong:

```
free(root)
```

will only free the root node, but will leak the child nodes...